# EmguCV capture rtsp ip camera stream ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, emgucv

I am working with IP camera and EmguCV to detect person in an area.
Everything is work normally with `Highgui` capture source.
But with Arlo camera which use `FFMPEG` format, I am unable to get stream without any exception.
Here is the code I have tried:

```
if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture("rtsp://<IP>:8554/live"); 
                capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed;
                capture.Grab();
                capture.Start();
            }


            catch (NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
            catch (TypeInitializationException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                   "Attention: You have to copy all the assemblies and native libraries from an official release of EmguCV to the directory of the demo." +
                   Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + exc);
            }
}
```

and here is `Capture_ImageGrabbed` event which is not fired.

```
private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mat image = new Mat();
        capture.Retrieve(image);
        picCAM.Image = image.Bitmap;
    }
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What is the exception? are the image formats you are getting the same?

Comment: As I said there is no exception.

Comment: What version of EmguCV are you using?

Comment: @Reynaldi: I use the newest version of EmguCV at that time: 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

This might be old, but until now I'm also facing the same issue, even using the newest version (which is version 3.3). Probably not the best solution, but after took some trial and error, what I did is to downgrade to version 2.4.2. You can download [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/2.4.2/).

I also recently submitted this issue in [github](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/94). This is probably a bug.

Comment: I will give it a try and tell you the result. Thank you so much for your help